# how to select most recent data in my table?

Tags: mysql, oracle

In my database have one table `AM_HISTORY` in that two columns like `USER_ID`,`SAVE_DATA`.

My Questions are...

How to select recent saved data in `AM_HISTORY` table?

How to select most 10 or 50 records in `AM_HISTORY` table?

please help...

```
USER_ID  SAVE_DATA  
   1     Data1 
   1     Data2 
   2     Data1 
   2     Data2
```

hear USER_ID 1 have data1,data2  and 2 have data1,data2(for ex..)
so i want user 1 recent data.
Please help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT * 
FROM AM_HISTORY 
ORDER BY ID DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming id increments only

```
SELECT * FROM AM_HISTORY ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10;
```